# How to integrate Signal-R support in a Blazor WebAssembly site (.Net 5)

Tags: signalr, blazor-client-side

I'm trying to get startet with Blazor Webassemblies (the standalone version).
Very nice, when you're an experienced C# programmer.

The trouble arises, when i try to integrate *Signal-R* in the same site, that delivers the pages i can't figure out, how to do that.

The client part of *Signal-R* is rather simple, but i don't want to create a separate site, since that ends in a CORS situation...

The only documentation i've been able to locate relates to Blazor Server, which i don't want to use.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can checkout my demo site for my Library,  its a working example of signal r with Blazor WASM https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/tree/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Demo.AspNetCore

Comment: Nice, but it looks as a classic MVC application, without the .razor pages i find in the Blazor app...

Comment: The Blazor client goes here https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/tree/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Demo.BlazorWasm/Client you can load the demo using SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Demo.sln

Comment: OK, i see i missed a checkmark in the project template.

I was looking for a way, where all code resided inside the same solution, like in an MVC application.

Comment: That's not possible with Wasm. You need a project that's build to binary and run inside wasm

Comment: Sorry misread, I though you said project. Yeah you will en up with a server host project and a wasm client project